# date column not converting into datetime type

Tags: pandas, datetime, python-3.5

I have the following dataframe df:

```
     Opname_start_date              Opname_end_date
0  2016-11-21 11:33:00  2016-11-23 12:02:59.0000000
1  2016-07-06 09:16:00  2016-07-06 09:16:01.0000000
2  2016-08-11 10:18:00  2016-08-15 10:40:59.0000000
3  2016-09-23 11:28:00  2016-09-23 11:28:01.0000000
4  2016-08-11 14:06:00  2016-08-11 14:06:01.0000000
5  2016-10-26 09:42:00  2016-10-29 11:25:59.0000000
6  2016-12-02 15:03:00  2016-12-09 14:00:00.0000000
7  2016-07-08 09:00:00  2016-09-27 09:15:01.0000000
8  2016-06-14 09:01:00  2016-06-17 13:00:00.0000000
9  2016-12-08 13:54:00  2016-12-08 13:54:01.0000000
```

I want to subtract Opname_end_date from Opname_start_date and would like to save it to a new column. I tried the following:

```
df['LOS'] = df['Opname_end_date'] - df['Opname_start_date']
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<U27') and dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

I checked the dtypes of the dataframe and it shows that first column is datetime64[ns] but the second column is still object. I tried to convert the second column using `pd.to_datetime(df['Opname_end_date'])` but it still shows that column is of type object and do not throw any error.
I am unable to figureout where the problem is. If someone can help me out, it would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working converting column `Opname_end_date` to `datetimes` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
print (df.dtypes)
Opname_start_date    datetime64[ns]
Opname_end_date              object
dtype: object

df['LOS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Opname_end_date']) - df['Opname_start_date']
```

Or:

```
df['Opname_end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Opname_end_date'])
df['LOS'] =  df['Opname_end_date'] - df['Opname_start_date']
```

---

```
print (df)
    Opname_start_date              Opname_end_date              LOS
0 2016-11-21 11:33:00  2016-11-23 12:02:59.0000000  2 days 00:29:59
1 2016-07-06 09:16:00  2016-07-06 09:16:01.0000000  0 days 00:00:01
2 2016-08-11 10:18:00  2016-08-15 10:40:59.0000000  4 days 00:22:59
3 2016-09-23 11:28:00  2016-09-23 11:28:01.0000000  0 days 00:00:01
4 2016-08-11 14:06:00  2016-08-11 14:06:01.0000000  0 days 00:00:01
5 2016-10-26 09:42:00  2016-10-29 11:25:59.0000000  3 days 01:43:59
6 2016-12-02 15:03:00  2016-12-09 14:00:00.0000000  6 days 22:57:00
7 2016-07-08 09:00:00  2016-09-27 09:15:01.0000000 81 days 00:15:01
8 2016-06-14 09:01:00  2016-06-17 13:00:00.0000000  3 days 03:59:00
9 2016-12-08 13:54:00  2016-12-08 13:54:01.0000000  0 days 00:00:01
```

Comment: Great. That seems to work. But I do not understand why it does not work if I convert the Opname_end_date column separately and then subtract? Why it was causing a problem that way and but your way, it works fine?

Comment: @HT121 - Hmmm, hard to know, do you assign back `pd.to_datetime(df['Opname_end_date'])` like `df['Opname_end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Opname_end_date'])` ?

Comment: No I didn't assign it back, so may be that was the problem. Thank you for your quick help.